# 'Tuple' object is not callable in classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning classes right now and every time that I try to run this code I get " 'tuple'  object is not callable'". I know that I can't access elements from a tuple using only parentheses I. Can someone tell what is wrong with my code?

```py
class Line:
    
    def __init__(self, coor1, coor2):
        self.coor1 = coor1
        self.coor2 = coor2

    def distance(self):
       return ((self.coor2([0])-self.coor1([0]))**2+(self.coor2([1])-self.coor1([1]))**2)**0.5
   
    def slope(self):
       return (self.coor2([1])-self.coor1([1]))/(self.coor2([0])-self.coor1([0]))

coordinate1 = (3,2)
coordinate2 = (8,10)

li = Line(coordinate1,coordinate2)

li.distance()
```

Comment: `coor2([0])` -> `coor2[0]` etc.

Comment: You're just randomly adding parentheses everywhere, some of them mean _calling_ what's not a function.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing `coor1` and `coor2` which both are tuples using round brackets, so Python tries to call them as a function and fails.

Remove the round brackets:

```
def distance(self):
    return ((self.coor2[0] - self.coor1[0]) ** 2 + (self.coor2[1] - self.coor1[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5

def slope(self):
    return (self.coor2[1] - self.coor1[1]) / (self.coor2[0] - self.coor1[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses around the indexing operations lead Python to attempt to interpret the tuples as functions. Remember that parentheses can change the semantic meaning of your code.

To resolve, remove the parentheses around the indexing operations:

```py
class Line:
    
    def __init__(self, coor1, coor2):
        self.coor1 = coor1
        self.coor2 = coor2

    def distance(self):
       return ((self.coor2[0]-self.coor1[0])**2+(self.coor2[1]-self.coor1[1])**2)**0.5
   
    def slope(self):
       return (self.coor2[1]-self.coor1[1])/(self.coor2[0]-self.coor1[0])

coordinate1 = (3,2)
coordinate2 = (8,10)

li = Line(coordinate1,coordinate2)

# Prints 9.433981132056603
print(li.distance())
```